# User Location is different on MKMap in iOS 7 from iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, mapkit

I'm creating a map app, where I want to set the user's location at the bottom center. For this purpose, I made my map double in height and width to set user location at desired location(I might have followed the wrong process for this, suggestions would be welcome).

Please see attached screen shots for `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` for change in location:

`iOS 6`

[image: iOS 6]

`iOS 7`

[image: iOS 7]

I want to make user location like it is in `iOS 6`.

Comment: Add the code you use to center the user's position at the bottom.

Comment: Did you run both the versions in a `3.5-inch` display simulator?
i.e. I doubt whether you run the `iOS 6` version in a `3.5-inch` display, and the `iOS 7` version in a `4-inch` display.

Comment: @CainaSouza To make the position in bottom center I just make the map double in size i.e. made the frame (-260, 0, 840, 1136).

Comment: @GoGreen Yes I run on both simulators, it wirks fine in iOS6, on both simulators, but causing issue on iOS 7.

Comment: Check the auto-layout properties. Maybe they are conflicting somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I've check auto-layout, but didn't find any solution.